# Have to reload AHK Script despite it being in startup folder

Tags: autohotkey

I have an AHK script that remaps my middle mouse button the Delete key. I have added this script, along with my other scripts, to the startup folder found by `shell:startup`. However, this script in particular does not work even if it is loaded automatically at startup. To make it work, I once again need to reload it by choosing the `Reload this script` option when you rightclick the script icon in the system tray. Only after reloading the script does the mapping work as normal. What can I change to make the script work the first time it's loaded like all of my other scripts?

Here's the script itself (simple enough...)

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

MButton::Delete
```

Comment: Strange. I too have my scripts in the shell:startup directory, and they always start without any problem. You could try looking at the file/link properties, select advanced and then Run as Administrator. Not sure if it will work and I didn't need that, but at least worth a try.

Comment: If you have many independent ahk scripts in shell:startup, it may be a problem. You could in your main.ahk script place the line `#Include %A_ScriptDir%\middle2delete.ahk`  in the middle2delete.ahk place your remapping `MButton::Delete` this way your ahk script works as one application. I use ahk this way and have several remappings without need to reload.

Comment: @Iww, your answer solved my issue. Could you post it as an answer so I may accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Iww successfully answered the question in the comments.

The problem was that there were too many autohotkey script shortcuts in the shell:startup directory. Placing each script as a #Include [directory][script].ahk into one main script and placing only a shortcut to main in shell:startup does the trick.